# How can i use Animator framework, which is new in android 4.0, on the platform before android 2.3?

Tags: android, objectanimator

How can i use Animator framework, which is new in android 4.0, on the platform before android 2.3 ?

thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Use [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/), Jake Wharton's backport of the animator framework.